Set Up Browser Extension Trust Wallet with the wong private keys
I had set up a Trust wallet on my iPhone. Recently I decided to set the Trust browser extension wallet on my computer. When I set the Trust wallet extension on my computer, I imported the wallet using the wrong private keys. I accidently used the private keys for my Metamask wallet. I did not realize I did this. I then sent ETH to the Trust wallet. I see that the transaction was completed but it has not appeared in my wallet. Is there any way to recover this?

Hey, it sounds like you should be fine, the wallet UI you use is totally irrelevant and acts only as an abstraction to make interacting with the chain easier. But what do you mean you sent them to the trust wallet? What address did you send them to if you hadn't set up any keys for it yet?
